# Question about project structure on IntelliJ with test automation

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, automated-tests

I am having some troubles when trying to use maven for regressive testing that will be implemented for my developer team. I need the maven to run its lifecycle, but when I run mvn test or install on my console, all that my current project does is to compile everything, but doesnt run the tests. Any idea how can I solve this? I am sending image on my project structure

[image: CTs image]

[image: Code image]

Comment: I couldn't quite tell from your images: Do you have the production sources under `src/main/java` and the test sources under `src/test/java`?

Comment: Please follow the standard Maven directories layout: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your maven structure.

- src/main/java is Sources Root
- src/test/java is Test Sources Root

Your code tree should like something like the following:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know this is the common pattern, but I need to change to adapt to my own structure. Any ideas which configuration in POM I need to change for that? There is the maven-surefire and maven-compiler